# Trying to get the javascript errors using selectpdf

Tags: selectpdf

Using selectPDF in C# to convert URLs to PDF.  It's obvious there are some javascript errors.  Is there a way to get the errors when the conversion happens so I can see what's going on?

Comment: Here is the answer to your question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62470550/selectpdf-not-showing-grid-data

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and added the following code to the top of my page to figure out the error. In my case the error was "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'" -- whatever browser that SelectPDF uses behind the scenes apparently doesn't support ES6.

```
<script>
    window.onerror = function (msg, url, lineNo, columnNo, error) {
        document.write('<p>Message: ' + msg + '</p>');
        document.write('<p>Script Url: ' + url + '</p>');
        document.write('<p>Line: ' + lineNo + '</p>');
    };
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you! I've looked everywhere and this is the only working answer I've found.

Answer (score 0):

*Disclaimer: I work for SelectPdf.*

Sorry for the late reply. Maybe it could help other people in the future.

To get the console log after conversion check *converter.ConversionResult.ConsoleLog*.

SelectPdf supports several rendering engines. The default WebKit rendering engine can render ES5 javascript. Blink engine can render ES6.

Comment: This is a C# call.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's a helpful property. What version did it become available in? It's not present in the one I'm using, 18.4.

Comment: It seems (out of the box) SelectPDF cannot handle ES6 commands?

Answer (score 0):

An additional approach is to use an old WebKit ES5 browser to view the page that is having problems - this allows interactive debugging and can help narrow down problems quickly.

I had success recently using Opera 15.0. Archived versions of Opera are currently available for download at: https://get.geo.opera.com/pub/opera/desktop/