# SelectPDF not Showing Grid Data

Tags: c#, selectpdf

I'm using [Select PDF - Community Edition](https://selectpdf.com/community-edition/) to render the output of a web page (e.g. document).  When I view the PDF...the data in the grids are empty.

- And yes, the grid data does render when viewed normally
- As a side-note...I am using Kendo Grids

As an experiment...I set the ["MinPageLoadTime"](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf-api/) property to 15 seconds...it does indeed take 15 seconds for the SAVE to execute...but oddly, still no records are displayed in the PDF's rendering of the grid.

```
public byte[] ToPDF(IPdfConverterArgs args)
{
    if (args == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    if (!(args is SelectPdfUrlConverterArgs))
        throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Args.Type '{0}' is not a valid type.", typeof(SelectPdfUrlConverterArgs).Name));

    var arguments = args as SelectPdfUrlConverterArgs;

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(arguments.Url))
        throw new ArgumentNullException();

    var pdfPageSize = (PdfPageSize)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageSize), arguments.PdfPageSize, true);
    var pdfOrientation = (PdfPageOrientation)Enum.Parse(typeof(PdfPageOrientation), arguments.PdfOrientation, true);

    HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

    converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pdfPageSize;
    converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = pdfOrientation;
    converter.Options.WebPageWidth = arguments.WebPageWidth;
    converter.Options.WebPageHeight = arguments.WebPageHeight;
    converter.Options.MinPageLoadTime = arguments.MinPageLoadTime; //<<< In my testing...I temporarily set this to 15 (for seconds)

    PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(arguments.Url);
    var bytes = doc.Save();

    return bytes;
}
```

NO GRID DATA in the PDF:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I work for SelectPdf.*

It could be a javascript error. Try to get the console log after conversion using *converter.ConversionResult.ConsoleLog*. See if there are any javascript errors.

- The ConsoleLog object does not exist in older versions
- Just upgrade to the latest version as listed [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Select.HtmlToPdf/)

SelectPdf supports several [rendering engines](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/RenderingEngine.htm). The default WebKit rendering engine can render ES5 javascript. Newer ES6 javascript syntaxes might result in errors.

```
HtmlToPdf converter = new HtmlToPdf();

converter.Options.PdfPageSize = pdfPageSize;
converter.Options.PdfPageOrientation = pdfOrientation;
converter.Options.WebPageWidth = arguments.WebPageWidth;
converter.Options.WebPageHeight = arguments.WebPageHeight;
converter.Options.MinPageLoadTime = arguments.MinPageLoadTime;

PdfDocument doc = converter.ConvertUrl(arguments.Url);
// At this point...you can look at the ConsoleLog object off of the ConversionResult to find any JavaScript Errors
```